# Can you have 2 solutions open simultaneously in Visual Studio Mac?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I'd like to have 2 windows open to copy files from one solution to another - can I open 2 windows at the same time with different solutions?  I can't seem to find the option to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible.
From the terminal, using:

```
open -n /Applications/Visual\ Studio.app
```

For example, in Xamarin you're also able to build and run different solutions on different platforms (Android/iOS) using simulators.

Answer (score 0):

From the terminal, you can open a new instance of an app by using

```
open -n /Applications/Visual\ Studio.app
```